# ItemAdd Event in Outlook Using VBA - Something Causing Listeners to 'UnSet' Randomly

Tags: excel, events, vba, outlook

I am using VBA with an event listener on a specific sub-folder to run a macro when that folder receives an email. It is working perfectly, with one exception. I am setting the objects to listen, but they are getting set back to 'nothing' seemingly randomly, which stops the listeners from 'listening'. Here's the code I am using to set the listeners and trigger the macros:

```
Public WithEvents myOLItems As Outlook.Folder
Public WithEvents myTDLoanEmails As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set myOLItems = Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myTDLoanEmails = myOLItems.Folders("Trust Loan Collateral Tracking Text Files").Items
End Sub

Private Sub myTDLoanEmails_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Call getAttachments
    Call runTextToExcel
End Sub
```

'runTextToExcel' creates an Excel application, opens an Excel file, runs a macro in that file, and then closes the file and the application. I think the error may be stemming from the file/Excel application not closing completely, because if I run the Outlook macro again immediately after completion, it cannot find the Excel file, despite the fact that hasn't moved. This causes an error, which I think may be 'unsetting' the listeners. Is this possible?

If it helps (or you're curious) here are the two subs that are called above:

```
Private Sub runTextToExcel()
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim oWbk As Workbook
Dim TextToExcelFile As Workbook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With xlApp
    .Visible = True
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

sFile = "Loan Text Files to Excel Converter_v004.xlsm"
sPath = "K:\Shared\Text to Excel\"

bOpened = False
For Each oWbk In Workbooks
    If oWbk.Name = sFile Then bOpened = True
Next oWbk
If bOpened = False Then Workbooks.Open (sPath & sFile)

xlApp.Run "'" & sFile & "'!LoanTextFilesToExcel"

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks(sFile).Close (True)
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True
xlApp.Quit

End Sub


Private Sub getAttachments()
    On Error GoTo GetAttachments_err

Dim ns As NameSpace
Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
Dim TDLoanEmails As MAPIFolder
Dim Item As Object
Dim Atmt As Attachment
Dim FileName As String
Dim i As Integer

Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set TDLoanEmails = Inbox.Folders("Trust Loan Collateral Tracking Text Files")

For Each Item In TDLoanEmails.Items
    If Item.Attachments.Count > 3 Then
        If Day(Item.ReceivedTime) = Day(Date) And Month(Item.ReceivedTime) = Month(Date) And Year(Item.ReceivedTime) = Year(Date) Then
            For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                If Right(Atmt.FileName, 4) = ".TXT" Then
                    FileName = "K:\Shared\Text to Excel\Text Files\" & Left(Atmt.FileName, Len(Atmt.FileName) - 4) & "-" & Format(Date, "mmddyyyy") & ".txt"
                    Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                End If
            Next Atmt
        End If
    End If
Next Item

GetAttachments_exit:
    Set Atmt = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Exit Sub

GetAttachments_err:
   MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
      & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
      & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: GetAttachments" _
      & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
      & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
      , vbCritical, "Error!"
   Resume GetAttachments_exit
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is because of the `runTextToExcel` But take a backup of your existing `runTextToExcel` and replace it with this.

I believe you are using `Late Binding`

Changes made in this code

1. Object Declared
2. Object Closed and Released properly

**Code**

```
Private Sub runTextToExcel()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim oWbk As Object, wb As Object
    Dim TextToExcelFile As Object '<~~ Are you using this anywhere?
    Dim bOpened As Boolean

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    With xlApp
        .Visible = True
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    sFile = "Loan Text Files to Excel Converter_v004.xlsm"
    sPath = "K:\Shared\Text to Excel\"

    bOpened = False

    For Each oWbk In xlApp.Workbooks
        If oWbk.Name = sFile Then bOpened = True
    Next oWbk

    If bOpened = False Then Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFile)

    xlApp.Run "'" & sFile & "'!LoanTextFilesToExcel"

    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb.Close (True)
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = True
    xlApp.Quit

    Set wb = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested (using the TextToExcelFile variable instead of wb, which was my original intention), but the instance of Excel is still hanging around in the task manager after it should be gone. Here's the code that I have now: http://pastebin.com/K9SJndBD 

Additionally, if I try to move the email into the folder with the listener again (after completion of the first run-through), I get an run-time error '462': The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable. Any idea what would cause this? Thanks again!